# Showing $T^{-1} = T^*$ where T is matrix of normalized eigenvectors of Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an nxn Hermitian matrix with n distinct eigenvalues and T be the matrix whose columns are normalized eigenvectors of A. I want to show that $T^{-1} = T^*$.

I know that the eigenvectors of A are mutually orthogonal, and since they are normalized, then they are orthonormal. Where do I proceed in showing that $T^{-1} = T^*$? Thanks.

Comment: Compute $TT^*$. Write $T = [t_1\ \ t_2\ \ \cdots\ \ t_n]$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof.

Let $T = \begin{bmatrix}t_1 & \cdots & t_n \end{bmatrix}$, where $t_j$'s are $n\times 1$ column matrices. Since $A$ is Hermitian with $n$ distinct eigenvalues, and $t_j$'s are normalized, $\{t_j\}_1^n$ satisfies $t_j^* t_k = \delta_{j,k}$, thus 
$$
T^* T = [t_j^* t_k]_{(j,k)=(1,1)}^{(n,n)} = [\delta_{j,k}] = I. 
$$